# How to send deposit and withdraw details of user from client to Node.js (express) server using Pusher?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, pusher, pusher-js

I am subscribing to "my-channel" and binding to "my-event" in client.

**pusher.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>Pusher Test</title>
  <script src="https://js.pusher.com/5.0/pusher.min.js"></script>
  <script>

    // Enable pusher logging - don't include this in production
    Pusher.logToConsole = true;

    var pusher = new Pusher('******', {
      cluster: 'ap2',
      forceTLS: true
    });

    var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');
    channel.bind('my-event', function(data) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    });

  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Pusher Test</h1>
  <p>
    Try publishing an event to channel <code>my-channel</code>
    with event name <code>my-event</code>.
  </p>
</body>
```

I am triggering "my-event" in "my-channel" with a message hello world

**server.js**

```
        var pusher = new Pusher({
            appId: '****',
            key: '****',
            secret: '******',
            cluster: 'ap2',
            encrypted: true
        });

        pusher.trigger('my-channel', 'my-event', {
            "message": "hello world"
        });
```

For this code i get an alert message in client side . i.e., my server is sending messages to client but my problem is i want the whole process other way around , i want client sending messages to the server and how to receive those in server?.How to do it with pusher using node.js.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client libraries provided by Channels can only subscribe to channels and consume events (they can also send events to other clients) - they cannot trigger events to the server.
Server libraries can only trigger events - they cannot subscribe to channels.

A solution could be achieved by using [client events](https://pusher.com/docs/channels/using_channels/events#triggering-client-events) and configuring the necessary [webhooks in your app](https://pusher.com/docs/channels/server_api/webhooks#client-events).

More info can be found in Pusher Channels [documentation](https://pusher.com/docs/channels/channels_libraries/libraries)